# How to get the clicked element in Bootstrap collapse event?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble to find the clicked anchor element in the collapse event using Bootstrap 3.3.4.:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    // Get clicked element that initiated the collapse...
});
```

I need this because I'd like to prevent collapsing if the clicked element has a certain data attribute. Another option would be to hook in by using `.on('click', function())`, however there are other events that occur on click that need to run so this seems a no-go to me. Searching in the DOM for the closest anchor or something similar won't work as well since there are multiple anchors next to eachother.

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/8s0mn0f4/5/** like this way you have multiple anchor tag?

Comment: The anchors are placed somewhere else on the page, all next to eachother (disregarding default Boostrap HTML structure).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since my case featured multiple anchors next to eachother (viz. disregarding regular Bootstrap structure), I ended up searching for the clicked anchor by using the collapsing div's ID:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    // Get clicked element that initiated the collapse...
    clicked = $(document).find("[href='#" + $(e.target).attr('id') + "']")
});
```

Comment: This will not work if the target in href is set as a class

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
$element.on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    var $clickedBtn = $(e.target).data('bs.collapse').$trigger;
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and will work no matter how the document is structured.

Comment: This only works for `shown.bs.collapse` event. Not for `show.bs.collapse` as data isn't set at the time.

Answer (score 3):

This is working in Bootstrap 4.2

```
$(".collapse").on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e){
    $clickedElement = $($(e.target).data('bs.collapse')._triggerArray);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$('#collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
   // Get the clicked button element's text...
   questionTitle = $(e.target).parent().find('button').text().trim();
   console.log(questionTitle); 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/8s0mn0f4/3/

```
    console.log($(e.target).siblings('.panel-heading').find('a'))
```

Comment: There are multiple anchors next to eachother. I only need the clicked one.

Comment: Then maybe write your own click listener on the links and don't use the bootstrap API

Answer (score 0):

This solution loops all collapse anchors and searches for the href target. It will work for both references by #id and by .class

In this example I use it to add the collapsed class to the clicked element.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        checkCollapsed();
    })

    function checkCollapsed() {
        $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            triggerCollapsedClass();
        }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            triggerCollapsedClass();
        });
    }

    function triggerCollapsedClass() {
        $("[data-toggle=collapse]").each(function (i, item) {
            var selector = $(item).attr("href");
            if ($(selector).hasClass("in")) {
                $(item).addClass("collapsed");
            } else {
                $(item).removeClass("collapsed");
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When bootstrap's collapse fires, and a div element is shown it's class becomes `panel-collapse collapse in`.

I needed this so I could ajax content into the newly opened panel. You can add an id or data- attribute to that element that can help identify the anchor.

HTML

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-X" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-x" id="accordionanchor-X">
Information X  
</a>
…
<div id="collapse-x" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pageheading-X">
    <div class="panel-body">
    …
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.collapse').on("shown.bs.collapse", function (e) {
   var clicked = $(".panel-collapse.collapse.in").attr("id");
   alert("collapse " + clicked);
});
```