# How to get event caller from listener function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the `caller element` from inside of an event listener function of `jQuery` using `Bootstrap3`.

Code:

```
jQuery(MoreOptionsCollapse).on('show.bs.collapse', function(event){
    console.log(this, event, event.target);
});
```

Console:
[image]

The problem is that `this` and `event.target` are the `MoreOptionsCollapse` element and what I want is the button that triggered the `show.bs.collapse` event.

Any help would be appreciated c:

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596773/how-to-get-the-clicked-element-in-bootstrap-collapse-event Neither ranking answer there is a perfect match, though.

Comment: You might just use a click listener on the triggering elements themselves.

Comment: I thought so too at the beginning but there will be more buttons triggering the same event, and what I want to do is change the caller element's text depending on the state of the collapse, wouldn't want to do messy code just for that :/

Comment: Understood. If you can switch to `shown.bs.collapse` you're golden. Otherwise it's probably not that difficult to get the collapse element associated with the trigger and check its state (`.in`).

Comment: well, you know that the original event target will be the element that was actually clicked... which will at the very least be inside the button, if it isn't the button itself. You could use traversal methods to go from there to your button if it isn't the button..

Comment: @isherwood Got it solved, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @isherwood in the comments and in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596773/how-to-get-the-clicked-element-in-bootstrap-collapse-event), you need to add a listener to the `shown.bs.collapse` instead of `show.bs.collapse` so that the `jQuery` element's `data()` can make time for `bs.collapse` to be `indexed` with the caller element set in `$trigger` key.

```
jQuery(MoreOptionsCollapse).on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    var triggerButton = jQuery(this).data('bs.collapse').$trigger[0];

    triggerButton.set('text', 'Some other text after element toggled');
});
```